# How to make a filename from partial string using NSPredicate then delete the file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I have files such as:

> RN150622103444544_pr.pdf
>      RN150622103444544_ID_GD.pdf
>      RN150622103444544_CA.xml

My question is how can I delete all the files only by referring the *RN150622103444544* part of their name **by using NSPredicate**.

Currently my code is deleting one by one:

```
-(void)deleteOldPdfs:(NSString *)proposal
{

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    if([fm fileExistsAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_pr_1.pdf",proposal]]])
       [fm removeItemAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_pr_1.pdf",proposal]] error:&error];

    if([fm fileExistsAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_id_GD.pdf", proposal]]])
       [fm removeItemAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_id_GD.pdf", proposal]] error:&error];

    if([fm fileExistsAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_CA.xml", proposal]]])
       [fm removeItemAtPath:[FormsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_CA.xml",proposal]] error:&error];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like the following which lists the contents of the directory and then filters those contents using a NSPredicate to only the paths containing your label.

```
- (void) deleteFilesContainingLabel:(NSString *)label{        
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    // Get the root directory path
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Create a predicate to filter out file paths containing the required
    // label.
    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS '%@'",label]];

    // List the directory
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    // Filter the list using our predicate
    NSArray *filteredFiles = [dirContents filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];

    // Delete the files which pass the predicate filter.
    NSError *error;
    for (NSString *path in filteredFiles){
      [fm removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is recommended by Apple to use NSURLs not path for file processing.

Comment: @Avt You can use either NSString or NSURL, although NSURL is quoted as 'generally preferred' in the manual. In this case I doubt there is much to be gained. It is pretty simple to change to using NSURL, but I just went for being as close to what the OP was using as possible.